# Testing if equality of array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the PHP below to test for types of shapes..e Rectangle, Squares etc.

```
if($this->noOfSides == 4 && count(array_unique($this->eachSides)) == 2) {
    $this->nameOfShape  = "Rectangle";
}

if($this->noOfSides == 4 && (count(array_unique($this->eachSides)) > 2)) {
    $this->nameOfShape  = "Quadrilateral (4 -Sided shape) with irregular sides";
}
```

Rectangle - 2 sides each are equal eg `4, 4, 6, 6`, the first section of the code applies, but when I enter values like `3, 3, 3, 4`, rectangle is echoed out again, rather than the second block.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean _enter values like 3, 3, 3, 4_. Where do you enter that?

Comment: Because in both cases You have 2 unique values (4,6) and (3,4).

Comment: @putvande I have a textbox where you can enter numbers of the sides you want to compute. So, `3, 3, 3, 4` are sides(length) of the shape

Comment: @Gustek How can I make sure that entries with only 2 pairs of equal lengths are echoed as Rectangle

Comment: None of 4,4,6,6 or 3,3,3,4 are rectangles. A rectangle would be 4,6,4,6. Order matters, array_unique will kill the logic

Comment: @CSᵠ unless OP has a specific order in which he/she sets the values. Like: left, right, top, bottom or something like that.

Comment: @putvande There are no specific order in which numbers are entered.

Comment: @putvande I would really not like to see that logic... by now, using array_unique it could imply the shape will be made a rectangle if possible...

Comment: Alright. How are you defining your shapes? Because if it doesn't matter, _4,4,6,6_ could be either a rectangle or an irregurlar shape.

Comment: @putvande Actually, I never put into consideration that 4,4,6,6 could actually be an irregular shape if opposite sides are not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simplifying your code a bit?

```
 if(count($this->sides) == 4) {
     if($this->sides[0] == $this->sides[2] && $this->sides[1] == $this->sides[3])
          $this->nameOfShape  = "Rectangle"; # actually, 'parallelogram'
     else
          $this->nameOfShape  = "Quadrilateral (4 -Sided shape) with irregular sides";
}
```

To detect other types of shapes, you're going to write further tests and also test angles along with sides:

```
     if($this->sides[0] == $this->sides[2] && $this->sides[1] == $this->sides[3])
          $this->nameOfShape  = "Parallelogram"; # can be rectangle, rhombus, square...
     else if($this->sides[0] == $this->sides[1] && $this->sides[2] == $this->sides[3])
          $this->nameOfShape  = "Kite";
     else 
          $this->nameOfShape # irregular or trapezoid...
```

This assumes that the adjacent sides of a shape are stored together:

```
           1
   +----------------+
   |                |
 0 |                | 2
   |                |
   +----------------+
           3
```

Comment: With input `4, 4, 6, 6` it will give the irregular shape.

Comment: @putvande code is good if you think about it, 4,4,6,6 *should* give a irregular shape... ps: read my comment on the question too

Comment: @putvande: I added more tests to the code.

Comment: @georg why `else if` and not `elseif`? ps: you should use `{` and `}` when using `if` and drop to a new line

Comment: @georg This tend to work only if the numbers are entered like `4,6,4,6`. If I do `4,4,6,6`, `Quadrilateral (4 -Sided shape) with irregular sides` is displayed...which is correct if that is the order in which the sides of the shape are numbered.... top, right, bottom, left.

Comment: @dotman14: added an illustration...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `array_unique` use [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

But don't just replace it in your code, using return value of this function check for square/rectangle and if not true, then in else you have quadrilateral.

For square you should have one key with value 4, for a rectangle two keys with value 2.

`array_count_values` will return

for 3, 3, 3, 4:

```
array(
    '3' => 3,
    '4' => 1,
}
```

and for 4, 4, 6, 6:

```
array(
    '4' => 2,
    '6' => 2,
)
```

Comment: Can you explain how OP will use this? Because this returns another array.

Comment: How will you ever learn anything about programming if you expect to receive ready to use code?? Think about it a little bit. You didn't even have enough time to read the manual....

Comment: I still get the same result. A shape of lengths `3, 3, 3, 4` still returns Rectangle. I used like this `count(array_count_values($this->eachSides)) > 2)`

Comment: @dotman14 read the manual it does not return the number of sides but the count of how many times each side shows so you need to either use `in_array` or loop on the result to check if any sides have the amount 4 or 2.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Do you have an explanation? I'm not asking for a code. Say what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the values and check that 1st==2nd && 3rd==4th.

Comment: If the shape has its length in the order of `4,4,6,6`, this is not a rectangle.

Comment: @dotman14: The question isn't clearly specified, but YOU say in the Q that that's a rectangle, so I assumed the order doesn't matter. That's why I can do sorting... Make up your mind.